# How to get the 1's complement of just necessary number of bits, rather than getting complement of all 32 bits representation of the number in java?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

```
int nm = 5;
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(nm));   // line 1
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(~nm));  // line 2
```

- line 1 gives --> 101
- line 2 gives --> 11111111111111111111111111111 010

I know the reason for the output of line 2.

What to do if I want line 2 output as 010 only(just the complement of 5(101), not the complement of 32 bit representation of 5)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bit-wise AND `~nm` with a number that has 1 bits in all the bits <= the highest 1 bit of `nm`. In the case of `5`, you have to bit-wise AND with `0b111`.

In general, you can compute the mask as follows:

```
System.out.println (Integer.toBinaryString ((-1 >>> Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros (nm)) & ~nm));
```

This will print `10`, not the `010` you wanted, since leading `0`s are omitted.

Explanation:

`Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros (nm)` will return `29` when `nm == 5`, so `-1 >>> 29` will return `0b00000..0111`.